# Change password not forcing new password on domain PC

Tags: azure, active-directory

We enforce password reset policy for our Office 365 users every 90 days.  I recently updated my password but my PC (joined to the domain) still is only using the old password.  How do I make it use the new password, and why isn't it asking me for the new password?

(I'm connected to the internet, restarted machine, locked machine, Windows 10, etc.)

Comment: You need to discuss this with your system admin. Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions.

Comment: @scrappedcola I am the system admin and Stack Overflow is the right venue as Azure directed me toward this.

Comment: Yes because Microsoft is SOOO afiliated with Stackoverflow. Look if you don't believe me then read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. You may be able to get help on ServerFault but this is not on topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @scrappedcola I will not believe you because this is the exact venue they recommended trying if you do not pay for a service plan.  Notice the tags, so go troll someone else

Comment: @scrappedcola https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/forums/

Comment: If you took the time to look around before posting then you would see that this site is about programming. If you go to http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/azure you will find configuration questions. If you have code post it but as you are asking about password policy then you need to post in the appropriate place. Just because MSFT decided to only post one part of the site doesn't mean your question is appropriate.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Run gpupdate /force. 
Then logout and back on. If that did not update your password, use this PowerShell Script
`$Expiration = (([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser –Identity '**username**' -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))-(Get-Date)).Days
Write-Output $Expiration`

See if this date is correct. 
If it is correct from when you last reset it, then you may have a corrupted profile.